# Como eu crio uma lista por arranjos para salvar uma struct?

Tags: c

Alguem me ajudaria a criar uma estrutura do tipo lista por arranjos para que eu possa implementar uma struct contendo um ID, uma prioridade (media, baixa, alta, urgente) e um telefone?

basicamente:

```
typedef struct Atividades{
      int id;
      int telefone
      char prioridade[20];
}
```

eu teria que gravar isso numa lista por arranjos, lista por arranjos só aprendi usando vetor, alguem saberia implementar utilizando struct?

Answer (score 1):

Esse código deve te ajudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct activity{
    int id;
    int phone;
    char prio[20];
};

typedef struct _list{
    // Armazena data
    struct activity *data;
    struct _list *next; //proximo item da list
}list;

// Adiciona na lista
void append(list **l, struct activity *ac){
    if(!*l){// insere o primeiro valor
        (*l) = (list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
        (*l)->data = (struct activity*) malloc(sizeof(struct activity));
        (*l)->next = NULL;
    }

    //Percorre até o final da lista
    list *swap = (*l);
    while((*swap)->next)
        swap = swap->next;

    //adiciona um novo item no final da lista
    swap->next = (list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
    swap->data = (struct activity*) malloc(sizeof(struct activity));
    swap->next->next = NULL;
}

// Remove um item do inicio da lista
void remove(list **l){
    if(*l){
        list *del = (*l);
        (*l) = (*l)->next;
        free(del);
    }
}
```

Comment: ajudou muito! valeu!

Comment: @ViníciusBarbosa se ajudou "muito", então marque a resposta como aceita